# What is the name of this table tennis equipment?

Tags: equipment, terminology, table-tennis

What is the name of the board/wall/plank that keeps table tennis balls from running too far away from the table? In this image, it is the purple and red board/wall/plank around the playing area that has "LIEBHERR" on it.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as "barriers." For more information on barriers, refer [here](https://www.tabletennisspot.com/best-brands-table-tennis-barriers/).

A preferred brand of table tennis barriers is Stiga:

[image: stiga barrier]

Here is an example of Stiga barriers being used during an informal competition:

[image: stiga barriers at competition]

Comment: Source: [All About Table Tennis](https://www.allabouttabletennis.com/table-tennis-room-size.html)

Comment: Author's note: It is not my source, but the aforementioned source did lead to providing this answer.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find any mention of them when googling using the word 'equipment'. Now I know :)